# d3.js liquid fill gauge clip-path not working

Tags: javascript, d3.js, typescript, angular

I'm trying to use [d3.js liquid fill gauge](https://gist.github.com/brattonc/5e5ce9beee483220e2f6) in my angular2 webapp, but the clippath not working, which means there's no wave created at all.

[image] rather than [image]

Since angular2 is running typescript, so I tweak something to fix syntax error. The code snippet of clip path is as below.

```
// The clipping wave area.
var clipArea = d3.svg.area()
.x(function(d) { return waveScaleX(d[0]); } )  // it was d.x in js version
.y0(function(d) { return waveScaleY(Math.sin(Math.PI*2*config.waveOffset*-1 + Math.PI*2*(1-config.waveCount) + d[1]*2*Math.PI));} )  // it was d.y in js version
.y1(function(d) { return (fillCircleRadius*2 + waveHeight); } );

var waveGroup = gaugeGroup.append("defs")
.append("clipPath")
.attr("id", "clipWave" + elementId);

var wave = waveGroup.append("path")
.datum(data)
.attr("d", clipArea)
.attr("T", 0);

// The inner circle with the clipping wave attached.
var fillCircleGroup = gaugeGroup.append("g")
.attr("clip-path", "url(#clipWave" + elementId + ")");    //clippath not working

fillCircleGroup.append("circle")
.attr("cx", radius)
.attr("cy", radius)
.attr("r", fillCircleRadius)
.style("fill", config.waveColor);
```

I've no idea how to fix it. Is it possible the change `return waveScaleX(d.x)` to `return waveScaleX(d[0])` fails it? But typescript doesn't accept the former syntax.

Comment: What's you data look like?  What error is typescript throwing?

Comment: @Mark if I use `d.x`, the typescript error is `Property 'x' does not exist on type [number, number]`. The `data` is an array created like `        var data = []; for(var i = 0; i <= 40*waveClipCount; i++) { data.push({x: i/(40*waveClipCount), y: (i/(40))}); }`

Comment: So, I just came back to this question.  I tried really hard to reproduce your error in [this example](http://plnkr.co/edit/hO43jixKR7D3IHWdmV29?p=preview).  I used typescript and angular2 (release candidate) and just can't replicate the errors.

Comment: @Mark Thanks a lot for your efforts! It's amazing! I notice that the difference of your example and my code is you import `liquidFillGuage` in the systemJS file and use it in angular2 as `import * as liquidFillGuage from 'liquidFillGuage';`  while I just copied those js code into my angular2 component and tweaked the code to fix syntax error. I also googled a lot these days, it seems that your method is what we're supposed to use a js file in angular2. I'll have a try.

Comment: @Mark by the way, I saw other article mentioned about create a `.d.ts` for the to be imported js file. You didn't do that but your code still works. What's magic at here?

Comment: I'm actually curious about that myself.  I expected to need definition files.  I'm curious if it's how plunker compiles the ts.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add location.href to the clip-path in liquidFillGauge.js

this:

```
var fillCircleGroup = gaugeGroup.append("g")
    .attr("clip-path", "url(#clipWave" + elementId + ")");
```

becomes this:

```
var fillCircleGroup = gaugeGroup.append("g")
    .attr("clip-path", "url(" + location.href + "#clipWave" + elementId + ")");
```

Here's my fork of the gist with the fix applied.
https://gist.github.com/jonbgallant/e85bc5440a4372aff9452e15a4e3276c

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I was finally able to reproduce your error.  First, **do not** just cut/paste the liquidFillGuage.js into your typescript file.  This is just not right on so many levels.  Then your question becomes, two parts, how do I include it and how do I get typescript to *know* about it.  With angular2, typescript and systemjs there's generally two ways to work.  One, is to use proper modules and import/require modules in your ts.  Two, is to `<script>` your dependency in and then set if up as ambient module so that typescript knows about.  For `d3`, the former works, but for `liquidFillGuage`, I'd use the latter.

Get `d3` installed:

```
npm install d3
typings install d3
```

In you systemjs.config.js, reference d3:

```
var map = {
  ...
  'd3':                         'node_modules/d3/d3.js'
  ...
};

var packages = {
  ...    
  'd3':                         { defaultExtension: 'js' }
  ...
};
```

In you index.html, include a `<script src=` to liquidFillGuage:

```
 <!-- 1. Load libraries -->
 <!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
 <script src="node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
 ...    
 <script src="some/path/to/liquidFillGauge.js"></script>
```

Now, here's the tricky part, how do we get typescript to know about `liquidFillGauge`?  Usually, for most things, [someone would have created](http://definitelytyped.org/) `.d.ts` file for it.  For something like this, though, you'll need your own.

In `typings/browser/ambient`, create a folder named `liquidFillGuage` and a file in that folder named `index.d.ts`, add to it:

```
declare function loadLiquidFillGauge(i: any, j: any): any;
declare function liquidFillGaugeDefaultSettings(): any;
```

This tells typescript about these functions and what parameters they take.

In `browser.d.ts` add a reference to this new `d` file:

```
/// <reference path="browser/definitions/liquidFillGuage/index.d.ts" />
```

And finally in your component file, tell typescript about this new ambient def:

```
/// <reference path="../typings/browser/ambient/liquidFillGuage/index.d.ts" />

import { Component, ElementRef, Renderer } from '@angular/core';
import * as d3 from 'd3';  //<-- we can do this because d3 is a proper module

 ...

 // typescript knows about this now!
 var gauge1 = loadLiquidFillGauge("fillgauge1", 55);
 var config1 = liquidFillGaugeDefaultSettings(); 

 ....
```

Comment: I really really appreciate your kind help!! But, unfortunately, this doesn't work either and the "wave" still fills all circle. I have two attempts. 1. doing exactly as yours except referencing d3 from webpack since I'm using it for my project. And the `/// <reference path="browser/definitions/liquidFillGuage/index.d.ts" />` should be `/// <reference path="browser/ambient/liquidFillGauge/index.d.ts" />` according to the folder structure. 2. instead of creating `d.ts` file, adding the two `declare function` statements to the components directly.   However, both attempts give me same result.

Comment: @BingLu, did you move liquidfillguage's out of your component and script src it in?. The error you are showing is leading me to believe that type script is attempting to compile that code.  It shouldn't be.

Comment: yeah, I totally removed the code of `liquidFillGauge` from my component. I created a folder under `src` folder and put the `liquidFillGauge.js` into it and added the `<script>` tag to `index.html`.

Comment: though the "wave" animation doesn't work, the value counting from 0 animation works. So, I think the `.js` file is successfully loaded and compiled but some other bugs of the `clip-path` fails the "wave" animation.

Comment: @Mark I am using angular2 webpack. How do I do this?