# typescript error: property x does not exist on type [number, number] when migrating javascript code

Tags: javascript, d3.js, typescript

I migrate this piece of code to typesript and get `property x does not exist on type [number, number]` error message.

```
var data = [];
for(var i = 0; i <= 40*waveClipCount; i++){
    data.push({x: i/(40*waveClipCount), y: (i/(40))});
}

var waveScaleX = d3.scale.linear().range([0,waveClipWidth]).domain([0,1]);
var waveScaleY = d3.scale.linear().range([0,waveHeight]).domain([0,1]);

var clipArea = d3.svg.area()
.x(function(d) { return waveScaleX(d.x); } )  //complain d.x at here and d.y next line
.y0(function(d) { return waveScaleY(Math.sin(Math.PI*2*config.waveOffset*-1 + Math.PI*2*(1-config.waveCount) + d.y*2*Math.PI));} )
.y1(function(d) { return (fillCircleRadius*2 + waveHeight); } );
```

So, the `data` is an array which contains object like `{x: 123, y: 456}`. The `waveScaleX` function just does a map from `domain` to `range`. Each element of `data` array will be fed to

```
function(d) { return waveScaleX(d.x); }
```

The `d.x` should have been quite straightforward and if I add a `console.log(d.x)` right before the `return` statement, the value is output correctly.

Any suggestion of fixing it?

PS. this question is related to `d3.js`, for more background, refer to my another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37056050/d3-js-liquid-fill-gauge-clip-path-not-working)

Comment: How do you apply `data`?

Comment: I'm going to close this and answer your other question.  It's considered bad form around here to ask multiple, duplicate questions on the same error.

Comment: @Mark Thanks. I also aware that.